# Apply CSS style to child nodes

Tags: javascript, html, css

Here is small fragment to serve as example:

```
<div id="parentDiv">
    <div>child1</div>
    <div>child2</div>
</div>
```

With CSS I can do this:

```
  div#parentDiv { position: absolute; }
  div#parentDiv>div { position: relative; }
```

How to do same styling with javascript?

Comment: The more efficient method would be define hierarchical CSS and use JS to add/remove classes on the children.

Comment: This is what you need :-http://stackoverflow.com/questions/195951/change-an-elements-css-class-with-javascript

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this: (*to just have only child elements, not all nested elements*)

```
var pDiv = document.getElementById('parentDiv');
var cDiv = pDiv.children;
for (var i = 0; i < cDiv.length; i++) {
    if (cDiv[i].tagName == "DIV") {   //or use toUpperCase()
        cDiv[i].style.color = 'red';  //do styling here
    }
}
```

**[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/venkateshwar/YeGZZ/)**

Not the best one, but you can refer the below: (*just for some more knowledge*)

```
Node.prototype.childrens = function(cName,prop,val){   
    //var nodeList = [];
    var cDiv = this.children;
    for (var i = 0; i < cDiv.length; i++) {
        var div = cDiv[i];
        if (div.tagName == cName.toUpperCase()) {
            div.style[prop] = val;
            //nodeList.push(div);
        }
    }
   // return nodeList;
}

var pDiv = document.getElementById('parentDiv');
pDiv.childrens('div','color','red');
```

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
    var parentDiv1 = document.getElementById('parentDiv');
    var childDiv = parentDiv1.getElementsByTagName('div');
    parentDiv.style.position = "absolute";
    for (var i = 0; i < childDiv.length; i++) {
        childDiv[i].style.position = "relative";
    }
```

Comment: You should replace `pDiv` in second line with `parentDiv`.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the following :

```
document.getElementById('parentDiv').childNodes[0].style.position = "relative";
document.getElementById('parentDiv').style.position = "absolute";
```